# XRegExp regular expression to allow single space between characters

Tags: regex, validation, xregexp

I am working with XRegExp Regex. I would like to have a space between my character also I need to have special characters enables. I have managed to add special characters allowed but I am not able to have a space allowed.

My regex `unicodeWord = XRegExp("^(\\p{L}|[0-9][\s])+$");`

It allows character like

> Wèlcome

but not

> Hi Wèlcome

```
//Alphanumeric validation
function isAlphanumeric(str) { 
    var unicodeWord = XRegExp("^[\p{L}\d]+(?:\s+[\p{L}\d]+)*$"); 
    result = unicodeWord.test(str);
    return result;
}


été altérée sûr générateurs
```

But this dosnt match this Alphanumeric.

Comment: escape the backslash one more time.

Comment: @Avinash Can I know on which position

Comment: `XRegExp("^[\\p{L}\\d]+(?:\\s+[\\p{L}\\d]+)*$");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your regex like,

```
unicodeWord = XRegExp("^[\\p{L}\\d]+(?:\\s[\\p{L}\\d]+)*$");
```

- `[\\p{L}\\d]+` Matches one or more letters or digits.
- `(?:\\s[\\p{L}\\d]+)*` followed by zero or more (*space followed by one or more letters or digits*)

OR

```
unicodeWord = XRegExp("^[\\p{L}\\d]+(?:\\s[\\p{L}\\d]+)?$");
```

`?` in `(?:\\s[\\p{L}\\d]+)?` would turn  the previous token `(?:\\s[\\p{L}\\d]+)` as optional.

Comment: How can I allow two spaces?

Comment: for one or more spaces inbetween `"^[\\p{L}\\d]+(?:\\s+[\\p{L}\\d]+)*$"` . For exactly 2 spaces `"^[\\p{L}\\d]+(?:\\s{2}[\\p{L}\\d]+)*$"`

Comment: It worked well.. How Can i make it work with Alphabets Allowing Accent Character and one or more spaces? Ex: été altérée sûr   générateurs

Comment: But it dosent match Can you check the updated Question.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:\\p{L}|[0-9\s])+$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iY3eK8/3

Comment: @TomPHP ADD special characters u want to d character class